# Syncing interaction between a GUI and a while loop

Tags: java, user-interface, interface

I'm currently programming a game in java and am using an interface to handle input/output for the game. I currently have a text interface working properly. I'm using code similar to the following:

```
while (moveExists())
{
    String in = interface.getInput();
    processInput(in);
    interface.displayOutput(this.getState);
}
```

The text only interface works because it pauses to wait for input, but I am not sure how to accomplish a similar behaviour in a GUI implementation. How may I 'wait' for input from an actionListener?

If not, I'll probably use code less like a game loop and more like a finite state machine so that I don't need to deal with two different threads trying to co-ordinate their actions.

Comment: "How may I 'wait' for input from an actionListener?" - you can't. Basically, the way a GUI works is that the GUI toolkit already runs a loop processing events. To maintain responsivity, these events must be handled quickly, which means no waiting for anything in them. Just do whatever is appropriate when the `ActionListener` that would submit a move is fired, unless that would take a long time.

Comment: @millimoose Thanks. It seems I wasn't wrong in believing it would be difficult at best. Currently, my game controls the interface. Do you think it would be better the opposite way around; make the UI control the game?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply start a GUI (that it has its own separated thread) containing a text area and maybe a button or something like that, then you add an ActionListener to the text area or button and then you execute the code you need when the Listener is triggered (i.e. some code has been inserted or button clicked).

Another story if you have also another 'background' thread that needs to run in a loop...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the 'other story'. My game is running a while loop but needs to wait until the swing GUI fires actionPerformed. It's like trying to rob someone without their wallet; you either run away, or wait for them to drive home and grab it.